# Updating a column by counting data from another table

Tags: postgresql, join, count, updates

I have two tables let’s say A & B and would like to count the results of column2 in table B by comparing them to table A column2 and update them in table A column1.

I am using the script shown here, but it's taking a really long time so I'd appreciate it if somebody could provide an alternative / better and faster option/script

```
UPDATE tableA
SET tableA.column1 = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                      FROM tableB 
                      WHERE tableA.column2 = tableB.column2)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. In questions like this it is helpful to add the `explain analyse` and the table structure, so that we can see if the indexes (if there are any) are being used. cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the proprietary `UPDATE ... FROM` to perform a join that can be something else than a nested loop:

```
UPDATE tableA SET tableA.column1 = tbc.count
FROM (SELECT column2,
             count(*) AS count
      FROM tableB
      GROUP BY column2) AS tbc
WHERE tableA.column2 = tbc.column2;
```